# Как получить сообщения из первой виртуальной консоли ubuntu 16.04

Tags: linux, ubuntu, ssh, консоль

Используя удалённый доступ необходимо видеть сообщения из первой виртуальной консоли, поэтому вопрос как попасть на первый терминал Ubuntu 16.04 из ssh, либо получить доступ к выводу каким бы то ни было иным способом.

Comment: Из `/dev/vcs1` вы можете прочитать текущий экран первой консоли. боюсь, что ничего сверх этого сделать не удастся

Comment: уточните, что значит «попасть», и что именно подразумеваете под «выводом комманд». вообще, конечно, можно читать и писать из/в `/dev/tty1` (пользователю, у которого есть на это права. см. `$ ls -l /dev/tty1`)

Comment: @alexanderbarakin мне нужен вывод команд в первую очередь. Спасибо буду пробовать

Comment: @alexanderbarakin хочу посмотреть что появляется на экране. Не знаю как правильно об этом сказать.

Comment: появляется откуда? подразумеваете сообщения, которые linux выбрасывает на первый виртуальный терминал? их можно посмотреть программой dmesg

Comment: @alexanderbarakin спасибо dmesg это именно то что мне было нужно

Comment: тогда внесите, пожалуйста, соответствующую правку в вопрос или удалите его вовсе.

Comment: @alexanderbarakin переформулировал так, чтобы потом можно было в поиске найти. Оформите пожалуйста ответ, я его зачту.

Comment: увы, формулировка не имеет никакого отношения к кольцевому буферу программы linux, который можно просмотреть с помощью программы dmesg. так что на ваш выбор: отвечайте сами на неправильно заданный вопрос, либо задайте его правильно (и сами ответ напишите), либо удалите вопрос вовсе. удачи!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

отобразит то что предоставляется пользователю

```
cat /dev/vcs1
```

за компанию команда которая отправляет на первую виртуальную консоль:

```
echo "hello" > /dev/tty1
```

чтобы получить вывод сообщений из кольцевого буфера, которые можно наблюдать например при загрузке ОС используют:

```
dmesg -w
```

Comment: А вообще есть ещё *ttysnoop*. Позволяет "подсматривать" за действиями пользователя на любой консоли.